# Array passed as parameter but reassignment within function fails?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, variable-assignment

```
function foo(a) {
  a = a.map(function(x) {return 0;});
}

var A = [1,1,1];
foo(A);         //seems like A should now be [0,0,0]
console.log(A); //nope its [still 1,1,1]. debugging shows that the parameter a in foo changes properly to [0,0,0] but does not transfer to A
A = [0,0,0];    //force A to [0,0,0] now
console.log(A);
function bar(a) {
  A = A.map(function(x) {return 1;}); //checking if i can force it back to [1,1,1] using this slight change
}
bar(A);
console.log(A); //this works
```

So why does foo not work?

A is passed into parameter a for `foo`, so foo's code should `run` as `A = A.map(whatever)`, just like in `bar?` I have some vague guess about it being how `javascript` handles `array` `pointers` in `assignment` or something.

Comment: Variables are passed by value in JavaScript. It's also case sensitive, so `A` !== `a`.

Answer (score 0):

Scope of 'a' is local to the function. You should be returning 'a' and assign it to 'A', something like

```
A = foo(A);
```

Answer (score 0):

Variables are passed by reference, so the assignment will not change anything *outside* of the function. The second function "cheats" a little because you declare `a` as the function argument but inside the function you reference `A` directly.

That said, from with the function you *can* modify the array itself:

```
function foo(a) 
{
    a.forEach(function(value, index) {
        a[index] = 0;
    });
}
```

Alternatively, return the new array from the function:

```
function foo(a)
{
    return a.map(function() { return 0; });
}

A = foo(A); // A is now modified
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @Jayachandran said, that 'a' is local to the *foo* function. You also need to return the result from the **a.map()** so that it can be assigned to another variable outside of the function (in this case, **A**).

```
function foo(a) {
    return a.map(function(x) {return 0;});
}

function bar(a) {
    return A.map(function(x) {return 1;});
}

var A = [1,1,1];

A = foo(A);     // Foo returns [0,0,0] as the result, but now we need to save it to A to replace [1,1,1].
console.log(A); // Hurray it's [0,0,0].

A = bar(A);
console.log(A); // Hurray it's [1,1,1] now.
```